# Python driver for Oracle 12c

Tags: python, oracle12c

I read the Oracle 12c [Application Development documentation](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/application-development/application-development-wp-12c-1896122.pdf) and noted with trepidation that Python support is mentioned only in the future tense:

> Scripting languages [...] will also benefit from these features once
>   the communities which maintain this code do the integration work.

Has anyone managed to get Python (esp. under Ubuntu) working nicely with an Oracle 12c database? If so, what drivers did you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would appear that one can still use older odbc libraries with Oracle 12. The
[Oracle Services Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/network.121/e17611/sqlnet.htm#NETRF2016) mentions SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_SERVER and SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_CLIENT settings that specify the minimum allowed versions permitted for connecting to and from the database. Both by default are set to 11, which amounts to Oracle Database 11g authentication protocols. So any driver for Oracle 11g clients should still work with an Oracle 12c database.

I've tested this out with a Java client using the ojdbc6.jar library for 11g connecting to my 12c Oracle database, and with version 5.1.2 of [cx_Oracle](http://cx-oracle.sourceforge.net/html/index.html) for Python.